# Cloud Firestore have queries “Strong Eventual Consistency”?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Given I have Cloud Firestore database and all the documents are created with `createdAt` field using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` with cloud-functions. I don't write/update/delete any document directly on Firestore.

If I querie all the documents until the date time now.

1. Will I querie all the documents until now? Or have any chance to appears some new document if I querie again using the last timestamp used? (Like a cloud-functions process creating some new document)
2. Does the querie result consistent? (Not change if the Cloud firestore not change the data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore has an immediately consistency model: once a write is completed, it is available to all clients and not just a subset of them.

This means that once a certain value of `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is written to your `createdAt` field, there will never be an older value that is written.

Comment: If I save the last timestamp from `createdAt` and use to querie new documents after the timestamp, will I get all the new documents? I need to use Equal/After or just After the timestamp to the all the new documents?

Comment: Yes, that approach could work. And you'd need an `>=` comparison, as the same value *can* appear multiple times.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen By "once a write is completed" are you referring to when the server SDK reports that the write has completed, or some more abstract notion of a write completing which makes sense for the Firestore internals?