# Is a single Firestore write operation guaranteed to be atomic?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a Chat document that represents a chat between two users. It starts out empty, and eventually looks like this:

```js
// chats/CHAT_ID
{
   users: {
      USER_ID1: true,
      USER_ID2: true
   },
   lastAddedUser: USER_ID2
}
```

Each user is connected to a different Cloud Run container via websockets.

I would like to send a welcome message to both users once the second user connected. This message must be sent exactly once.

When a user sends a "connected" message to its websocket, the container performs something like the following:

```js
// Return boolean reflecting whether the current container should emit the welcome message to both users
async addUserToChat(userId) {
  // Write operation
  await this.chatDocRef.set({ activeUsers: { [userId]: true }, lastAddedUser: userId, { merge: true })

  // Read operation
  const chatSnap = await this.chatDocRef.get();
  const chatData = chatSnap.data();
  return chatData.users.length === 2 && chatData.lastAddedUser === userId;
}
```

And there is a working mechanism that allows container A to send a message to a user connected to container B.

The issue is that sometimes, each container ends up concluding that it is the one that should send the welcome message to both users.

I am unclear as to why that would happen given Firestore's "immediately consistency model" ([per this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341168/cloud-firestore-have-queries-strong-eventual-consistency#:%7E:text=Firestore%20has%20an%20immediately%20consistency,just%20a%20subset%20of%20them.)). The only explanation I can think of that allows racing condition is that write operations involving multiple fields are not guaranteed to be atomic. So this:

```js
await this.chatDocRef.set({ activeUsers: { [userId]: true }, lastAddedUser: userId, { merge: true })
```

actually performs two separate updates for `activeUsers` and `lastAddedUser`, opening the possibility for a scenario where after partial update of `activeUsers` by container A, container B completes the write and read operations before container A overwrites `lastAddedUser`.

But this sounds wrong.

Can anyone shed light on why racing conditions might occur?

Answer (score 0):

I no longer have racing conditions if I base the logic on the server timestamps instead of the `lastAddedUser` field.

The document is now simpler:

```js
// chats/CHAT_ID
{
   users: {
      USER_ID1: true,
      USER_ID2: true
   }
}
```

And the function looks like this:

```js
// Return boolean reflecting whether the current container should emit the welcome message to both users
async addUserToChat(userId) {
  // Write operation
  const writeResult = await this.chatDocRef.set({ activeUsers: { [userId]: true }, { merge: true })

  // Read operation
  const chatSnap = await this.chatDocRef.get();
  const chatData = chatSnap.data();
  return chatData.users.length === 2 && writeResult.writeTime.isEqual(chatSnap.updateTime);
}
```

In other words, the condition for sending the welcome message now becomes: the executing container is the container responsible for the update that resulted in having two users.

---

While the problem is solved, I am still unclear as to why relying on document data (instead of server metadata) opens up the possibility for racing conditions to occur. If anyone knows the explanation behind this phenomenon, please add an answer and I'll accept it as the solution to this question.